# Does all the input function use the same buffer?

Tags: c

Does all the input functions use the same buffer? I read it in a book   It says that all the input functions use the same buffer in a program.But I made a test, it shows that maybe it's wrong. I want to know that is there any problem in my test?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE    *fp1; 
    FILE    *fp2;
    char    ch;
    char    ch2;
    int d;

    scanf("%d", &d);

    fp1 = fopen("file1.c","r");
    fp2 = fopen("file2.c", "r");

    while((ch = getc(fp1)) != 'r')
        putchar(ch);
    putchar('\n');

    putchar(ch = getc(fp1));
    putchar('\n');

    while((ch2 = getc(fp2)) != 'n')
        putchar(ch2);
    putchar('\n');

    putchar(getc(fp1)); 
    putchar('\n');

    putchar(ch2 = getc(fp2));
    putchar('\n');

    putchar(getchar());
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;

}
```

contents of the file1.c is:    the first one

contents of the file2.c is:    the second one

when I entered: `12cd`
the output is:

```
 the fi

 s

 the seco

 t

 d

 c
```

It seems that file1.c file2.c and stdin use three different buffers, Can you tell me is there any problem of my test? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: All properly opened FILE streams in C (and C++, but I fail to see any evidence of that language in this code) have their own dedicated stream buffer, if that is what you are asking (hard to tell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the book means that all the functions that reads from standard input have the same buffer.

In your example, you read from different files, every file will have their own stream, so they will have different buffers.

C11 7.21.3 Files

> A stream is associated with an external file (which may be a physical device) by opening
>   a file, which may involve creating a new file.

Then later the standard keeps talking about how to treat streams with different buffers(full, line, or unbuffered). Apparently buffers are relevant to streams, and streams are to files.

In C++, it's similar.

Comment: well,I also want to know what is the relationship between stream and buffer,can you tell me ?

Comment: @XianB The operation system will allocate a buffer for each stream, it's either fully buffered, line buffered, or unbuffered. There are some library functions like `setvbuf` that can manipulate them. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will recommend you to use other extension for your text files.

Obviously there is different streams or buffers in which you can read or write. The example that you have been wrote is a good prove of that.

Your program works perfectly fine.